# Plugin Development for registered users

Tags: plugin-development, database, login, forms, membership

I am new to plugin development for Wordpress but not new to software development.

This question is to get an idea of the "best practice" style for the following question.

I need to make a form only available to registered users, who ideally have a username that is a specific numbers-only is that they already would have. Ideally, the user would register with this id as their username, their email, name etc. After logging in, they would have access to a form that would be created by a plugin. When they submit the form, it would add data to a custom table created by the plugin. I've seen a lot of resources for managing tables in Wordpress, so that's not an issue.

Is there a members plugin that has an API that would allow me to track their id (username) when they submit the form? Should I use the default user capability? What would be the best practice for this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> only available to registered users

If the users are logged in, there have a username and ID to identifier. WordPress have functions to get this data, easy to use. You get as as example the user datas via [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/) and only the ID of the logged in user via [`get_current_user_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/). The documentation of the functions is inside the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/), there have a lot of documentations about this topic, also examples.